# PK mode for table 'SAMPLE' is RECORD_VALUE with configured PK fields [rollno], but record value schema does not contain field: rollno

Tags: mysql, json, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to pull data from json (SFTPJsonSourceConnector) to MySQL DB (JdbcSinkConnector). Please find below the Input and configuration files and got the below error.

```
[2022-07-31 00:03:20,239] ERROR [local-mysql-snik|task-2] WorkerSinkTask{id=local-mysql-snik-2} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:207)org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.at apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table 'SAMPLE' is RECORD_VALUE with configured PK fields [rollno], but record value schema does not contain field: rollno
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extractRecordValuePk(FieldsMetadata.java:279)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:104)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:66)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:116)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:584)
```

**Input file:**

`{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "int32", "field": "rollno"}, {"type": "string","field": "first_name"}],"name": "simple"},"payload": [{"rollno": 2,"first_name": "Sai"},{"rollno": 3,"first_name": "kumar"}]`

**Connect-standalone.properties**

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter   
> schema.generation.enabled=true    key.converter.schemas.enable=false
> value.converter.schemas.enable=true
> internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false    
> internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false    
> offset.flush.interval.ms=10000  
> plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/home/local/confluent-7.2.1/share/confluent-hub-components
```

sftp-source.properties

```
name=local-JsonSftp    tasks.max=3 connector.class=io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpJsonSourceConnector
> input.path=/home/local/confluent-7.2.1/path/to/data   
> error.path=/home/local/confluent-7.2.1/path/to/data   
> finished.path=/home/local/confluent-7.2.1/path/to/data
> cleanup.policy=NONE    input.file.pattern=simple-test.json    
> behavior.on.error=IGNORE  sftp.username=myuser   
> sftp.password=user@123    sftp.host=localhost    sftp.port=22
> kafka.topic=SAMPLE    schema.generation.enabled=true
> value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
> key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
> value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> key.converter.schemas.enable=false   
> value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

mysql-sink.properties

```
name=local-mysql-snik onnector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector   
> tasks.max=3      topics=SAMPLE
> connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdetails?user=root&password=user@321
> connection.user=user1     connection.password=user@321   
> schema.generation.enabled=true
> value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081       
> key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter    
> value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> key.converter.schemas.enable=false    
> value.converter.schemas.enable=true   auto.create=true   
> auto.evolve=true    insert.mode=upsert    pk.mode=record_value
> pk.fields=id
```

Note : The table created and inserted as struct {}
When I used pk.mode=record_key.

Comment: I include schema registry url and value.schema after that also facing same issue.  
    value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081                             
   value.schema={\"name\" : \"msgSchema\",\"type\" : \"STRUCT\","isOptional" : false,\"fieldSchemas\" : {\"rollno\" : {\"type\" : \"INT32\","isOptional" : false},\"name\" : {\"type\" : \"STRING\",\"isOptional\" : false}}}}

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is a Struct, but your payload is a list. Therefore, as the error says, your payload has no singular field `rollno`; there are multiple, and the sink connector will not iterate all values within the list, as it always treats each Kafka record as a single database entry.

So, you need two Kafka messages including payloads like this for that schema

```
"payload": {"rollno": 2,"first_name": "Sai"} 
"payload": {"rollno": 3,"first_name": "kumar"}
```

If the SFTP source is unable to generate records like that, then you'll need to use a stream processor such as Kafka Streams to do a `flatMap`  operation to split the list into individual records and write to a new topic to be consumed by the JDBC Sink.

You can also remove `key.converter.schemas.enable` setting since strings have no schemas that can be enabled. This property is only relevant to the JSON converter. You're also not using a schema registry.

All the internal converter properties should also be removed as they've been deprecated for several releases